# I suffer from chronic back issues, is full suspension bicycle good in that case?

Tags: suspension, off-road, pain, india

I live in India and moreover I have back issues.

Every Indian knows the condition of roads in India.

Is it advisable to buy a full suspension to get a easier ride for me or it makes no difference compared to a hardtail bike.

Moreover, are there any modifications that can make a bicycle immune to shocks?

Impacts are more of an issue than position.

Comment: Think about a suspended seat post, whatever bike you get

Comment: Depends on your back issues. Are they primarily caused by a hunched over seating position or by impacts from rough roads? In the later case various forms of suspension can help: Full suspension MTB, suspended seat post, wide low pressure tyres etc.

Comment: Impacts are more of an issue.

Comment: We generally consider medical advice off-topic.  Without knowledge of your condition the answers might prompt you to do things which are bad for you.  Please think through how you personally would experience any suggestions made in answers.   If your conditions are severe enough, cycling may not be in your future, sorry.

Comment: @Criggie: I think it very much depends on OP’s condition. Harsh impacts can’t be ruled out on a bicycle, even on a full suspension MTB. If such impacts could exacerbate a medical condition or cause permanent damage you are right that OP should consider not bicycling (if possible).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom bike to offer smoothest possible ride on bad roads](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/custom-bike-to-offer-smoothest-possible-ride-on-bad-roads)

Comment: Note that a suspension arrangement that is overly "mushy" can exacerbate the bouncing.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks Add more damping then to control the hyperactive suspension.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for your specific case but at least two friends have been advised by different physios to consider a full suspension bike if they want to continue mountain biking with their individual back conditions *which may or may not be the same as yours*.

If you are simply riding on the road, even very bad roads, I would not think this is such a concern as when riding purpose built trails or bike parks where technical sections may include drop offs and terrain that's usually considered impassible for cars.

It is not a bad idea to try but you would be best to consult a back expert before investing money in a new bike.

Comment: Even dirt roads would be fine on a hardtail (and many would be fine without suspension even with a bad back), but big unavoidable potholes are comparable to small drop-offs.  The worst roads I've seen in India were supposedly tarmacced but rougher than my local MTB trails and too busy to go round the potholes if there even was a way round.  In the UK when the surface gets that bad it's normally on almost deserted roads

Comment: I think this depends a lot on circumstances. A good hardtail MTB with wide, supple, low pressure tyres and a fairly aggressive seating position (-> more weight on the hands) can be better for the back than a cheap Fully with a bad suspension. Especially if it’s more about high-frequency vibrations from e.g. cobblestones or rough gravel.